# How would you rewrite this pseudo code?

Tags: loops, for-loop, pseudocode

Hey guys just doing some code practice and I came across this question it reads, Rewrite the pseudo code so that a FOR loop is used instead. Just wondering how you would do it cause I'm very lost. thanks for the help

```
value = 0.0
 While value <= 1.0
    OUTPUT value
   value = value + 0.1
ENDWHILE
```

Comment: What is the problem about that requirement ? **How would you do it?** Please don't ask question without showing at least a bit of effort ...

Answer (score 0):

"Pseudocode is subjective and nonstandard. There is no set syntax that you absolutely must use for pseudocode, but it is common professional courtesy to use standard pseudocode structures that other programmers can easily understand. If you are coding a project by yourself, then the most important thing is that the pseudocode helps you structure your thoughts and enact your plan. If you are working with others on a project—[...]—it is important to use at least some standard structures so that everyone else can easily understand your intent."[link](https://www.wikihow.com/Write-Pseudocode)

It won't be of any help to you if someone else rewrites this code for you. You should first understand what are the benefits of using pseudo-code and what are the common structures and then try to answer your own question. If you cannot manage to get the right answer, come back and ask for help on the piece of code you wrote. Try reading the link I provided or any other pseudocode tutorial and then try solving the problem. It might be hard at first but will bring a lot more benefits in the end.

Answer (score -1):

```
for value = 0.0 to 1.0 step 0.1 do
    output value
```

`step` is meant to describe the changes to `value` after each iteration